# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 after adding the cpp file

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a raytracer in c++ and I have a compilation issue on one of the classes. Basically the program runs well if all the code is stored in the header file, but once I move it in its corresponding cpp file it gives this error:

```
g++ -O3 -c main.cpp -I "./"
g++ main.o -o raytracer.exe
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Plane::Plane(Vect, double, Color)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [raytracer] Error 1
```

The code from the header file (Plane.h) is:

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

#include "math.h"
#include "Object.h"
#include "Vect.h"
#include "Color.h"

class Plane : public Object
{
private:
    Vect normal;
    double distance;
    Color color;

public:
    Plane();

    Plane(Vect n, double d, Color c);

    Vect GetPlaneNormal()     { return normal;   }
    double GetPlaneDistance() { return distance; }
    virtual Color GetColor()  { return color;    }

    virtual Vect GetNormalAt(Vect point);

    virtual double FindIntersection(Ray ray);
};

#endif // PLANE_H
```

And the implementation (Plane.cpp):

```
#include "Plane.h"

Plane::Plane() 
{
    normal   = Vect(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    distance = 0.0;
    color    = Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
}

Plane::Plane(Vect n, double d, Color c)
{
    normal   = n;
    distance = d;
    color    = c;
}

Vect Plane::GetNormalAt(Vect point)
{
    return normal;
}

double Plane::FindIntersection(Ray ray)
{
    Vect rayDirection = ray.GetRayDirection();

    double a = rayDirection.DotProduct(normal);
    if (a == 0)
    {
            // ray is parallel to our plane:w
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        double b = normal.DotProduct(ray.GetRayOrigin().VectAdd(normal.VectMult(distance).Negative()));
        return -1 * b / a - 0.000001;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to add to make the issue disappear? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `plane.cpp` in your compilation command

```
g++ -c main.cpp plane.cpp
```

then link both object files

```
g++ -o raytracer main.o plane.o
```

Or, better, learn how to use some modern build system, such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), it will come very handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> g++ main.o -o raytracer.exe

Your Plane.cpp function was presumably compiled into plane.o. The linker is complaining because you haven't given it plane.o to link. Try:

```
g++ <put all your .o files here> -o raytracer.exe
```

... or just compile and link all in one go.

```
g++ <put all your .cpp files here> -O3 -I "./" -o raytracer.exe
```

(i.e. compile without the -c flag)